# In redux, why do we have to keep the state immutable in reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, immutability

I wonder why we should keep the state immutable in reducers. Is that mandatory or simply a recommended approach? Does redux take advantage of the immutability thing to do some optimization?

After some experiments, I find that redux does make use of this immutability thing. One evidence for that is when we return the same reference to the state from reducers, the UI doesn't get updated as it should, even if data inside the state has changed.
As in the example below:

```js
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'BRING_UP_NEXT_IMAGE':
    state.push(state.shift());
    break;
  default: 
   return state;
 }
 return state;
};
```

The UI doesn't update because Redux detects the same state reference (for what it's worth).

This explains the necessity that we must return a new reference to the state if we want to update the UI. 
But why Redux requires that the internal state structure should be immutable as well? From what I can see, whether the UI gets updated solely depends on whether the state reference itself is changed. Even if I mutate the internal structure, the app works normally as well, as in:

```js
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'BRING_UP_NEXT_IMAGE':
    state = state.concat(state.shift());
    break;
  default: 
   return state;
 }
 return state;
};
```

Yes, I do mutate the previous state with "state.shift()", but since state.concat returns a new reference to the array, the state itself is a different reference and the app works normally.

In a nutshell, what I want to know is that whether the state should be strictly kept immutable is a necessity to make Redux function correctly, or a recommended option so that the app can achieve better performance by enabling shallow comparing in shouldComponentUpdate to bypass the reconciliation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discussed this in depth in my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/).  Quoting the summary section:

> The core Redux `createStore` function itself puts only two limitations on how you must write your code: actions must be plain objects, and they must contain a defined `type` field.  It does not care about immutability, serializability, or side effects, or what the value of the `type` field actually is.
>
> That said, **the commonly used pieces around that core, including the Redux DevTools, React-Redux, React, and Reselect, *do* rely on proper use of immutability, serializable actions/state, and pure reducer functions**.  The main application logic may work okay if these expectations are ignored, but it's very likely that time-travel debugging and component re-rendering will break.  These also will affect any other persistence-related use cases as well.
>
> It's also important to note that **immutability, serializability, and pure functions are not enforced in any way by Redux**.  It's entirely possible for a reducer function to mutate its state or trigger an AJAX call.  It's entirely possible for any other part of the application to call `getState()` and modify the contents of the state tree directly.  It's entirely possible to put promises, functions, Symbols, class instances, or other non-serializable values into actions or the state tree.  You are not *supposed* to do any of those things, but it's *possible*.

The details of how and why Redux relies on immutability are also discussed in the Redux docs, in the [Immutable Data FAQ section](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that "redux functions correctly" when components re-render on store changes they subscribe to then it only functions correctly if you return a new copy of your state.

redux' connect method has implemented a default shouldComponentUpdate which does include an identity check.

If you modify the state directly without creating a new identity, you would not only modify the new state but also the old state cause both point to the same reference on the store. Having the same reference will cause this.props.somePropFromStore === this.nextProps.somePropFromStore to be always true. This would cause redux to not detect state-changes anymore, unless you implement your custom behaviour.

So I would say it is more than a "recommended option", cause if you would bypass the basic principle of redux "never mutate data" you could replace the redux store engine with a global store-like variable that keeps all the information.

There is also a section in the redux documentation explaining it: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#why-isnt-my-component-re-rendering-or-my-mapstatetoprops-running

Answer (score 0):

In react lifecycles method `componentWillReceiveProps`, `shouldComponentUpdate` and `componentWillUpdate` if you mutate state nextProps and this.props will be the same. It generate hard to debug problems.